# Implementing django template cache in base template

Tags: django, caching, django-templates

I want to implement caching in  a base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load cache %}
{% load app_config %}{% verbose_name 'polls' as app_name %}
<head>
    {% cache head %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - {{ app_name }}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/css/style.css' %}" />
    {% endcache %}
</head>
<body>
    {% cache header %}
    <h2 id="header"><a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">{{ app_name }}</a></h2><hr/>
    {% endcache %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

There are two problems:

- verbose_name templatetag is always executed. How could I prevent this?
- the timeout of None, which means that it never expires, is not accepted by the template tag.

Answer (score 1):

About your timeout, you need to define a timeout in second, [check documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)

```
{% cache 300 header %} ... {% endcache %} # 300 seconds
```

You need to add a condition to execute your `verbose_name` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load cache %}
{% load app_config %}
{% if condition %}
{% verbose_name 'polls' as app_name %}
{% endif %
<head>
```

Comment: I know that a timeout must be set but I want to set the value to None. (infinite)

Comment: Hum I think is impossible for 1.10 version. In developpement version they add this featuer. You will be use None : [Documentation Developpement Version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)